# JSF composite components: optional attribute should default to another (required) attribute's property

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have a composite component (for search components), like:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="dialogWidgetVar" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="dialogTitle" required="false" default="Search Employees" />
    <cc:attribute name="dialogWidth" required="false" default="770" />

    ...

    <cc:attribute name="searcherBean" required="false" default="#{cc.attrs.managerBean.searcher}" />
    <cc:attribute name="managerBean" required="true" />

</cc:interface>
```

Note the line

```
    <cc:attribute name="searcherBean" required="false" default="#{cc.attrs.managerBean.searcher}" />
```

trying to reference the managerBean's searcher, if none was provided/overridden.

This throws and exception from the UI:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/components/company/genericSearcherDialog.xhtml @32,133 rendered="#{cc.attrs.searcherBean.quickSearchEnabled}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'quickSearchEnabled'.
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:413)
        ...
```

The searcherBean default seems to be strictly interpreted as a string, hence this is more or less a follow-up exception.

Changing the order of attributes does nothing.

**Q**:

How do you **default to another (required) attribute's field in a composite component interface** (without going to the UI code)? How is it done *alternatively* ("state-of-the-art")?

Thanks

Comment: What JSF impl/version? Tried the latest if not? Mojarra had some bugs related to default attribute type, which is IIRC fixed somewhere around 2.1.18.

Comment: Hmmm we're using Mojarra 2.1.14. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: We switched to Mojarra 2.1.22 and there's still the same exception.

Comment: What if you explicitly specify the `type`?

Comment: No difference. I used `<cc:attribute name="searcherBean" required="false" default="#{cc.attrs.managerBean.searcher}" type="de.company.compliance.common.view.search.framework.GenericSearcher" />` but it still says "The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'quickSearchEnabled'."